# Regex for two characters followed by four numbers

Tags: regex

I want to get an expression where first two letter should start with FP and followed by any four digit number.

I tried-

```
[FP][0-9]{4}
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove `FP` from the character class because `[FP]` matches only a single character from the list ie, `F` or `P`. Use anchors to do an exact string match. Without anchors, `FP[0-9]{4}` may match at the middle or at the end of a string , ie `FP[0-9]{4}` regex will match `FP1234` from `foo FP1234` string also.

```
^FP[0-9]{4}$
```

or

Remove the end of the line anchor if necessary `^FP[0-9]{4}`